# MSVC++ 2012 CTP struggling with variadic templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, variadic-templates

My goal is to create a functor type class that can save the parameters of a function so that it may execute it at a later time.  The idea is to pack the arguments into a `tuple`, and then unpack them into the `func` functions.  This is a thrown together example with some copy/move issues, but it'll do for now.  The MSVC++ 2012 CTP compiler struggles with the following code.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<int... I> 
struct Sequence {};

//make this pass the package to func, which will do nothing with it
template<typename... Args>
struct Dispatcher{
    //A tuple that holds all of the arguments
    tuple<Args...> argPackage;

    //A constructor that fills the tuple with arguments
    template<typename... CArgs>
    Dispatcher(CArgs&&... args) : argPackage(forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    //A function that takes the arguments and does nothing
    template<typename... Args> 
    void func(Args&&... args){}

    //A function that unpackes the tuple into func(), MSVC can't do this but GCC can
    template<int... I>
    void dispatch(Sequence<I...>){ //line 25
        func(forward<Args>(get<I>(argPackage))...); 
    }
};

int main(){
    Dispatcher<string,string,string> d("str1","str2","str3");
    d.dispatch(Sequence<2,1,0>());
    system("pause");
}
```

The compiler gives this error:

```
1>c:\users\jeremy\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\test\main.cpp(25): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1453)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
```

Now in its defense, the compiler does say the following warning.

> Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP' is for testing purposes
>   only

I have not tested this exact code with `g++`, but my main project has been successfully compiled by `g++` which contains the same methodology in a more complex scenario.

What can I do to make this dispatch function easier on the compiler so that it doesn't freak out?  Should I just manually unroll the dispatch function up to a certain point rather than making it a vardiadic template?  If so, how can I manually unpack the `Args` type one at a time?

Comment: Use MSVC 2013 RC instead. (I just tested and it compiles it fine) (also note `void main` should be `int main`)

Comment: @JesseGood I just upgraded and now it works fine as you said.  Thank you!